# How do I add a class to <body> that is generated by <?php body_class(); ?>>

Tags: css

I need to add a class of "two-sidebars" to the regular bunch of WP classes that are generated by `<?php body_class(); ?>>`

The reason I need to do this is I'm integrating WP into a Drupal install, and need to keep the "two-sidebars" class for style reasons for the Drupal part of the page.

What's the best way? jQuery? Is it possible to hook into body_class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add to the function simply by placing the desired class as the first parameter like so `body_class('class-name')`.

If you'd like a little more flexibility you can hook into it using `add_filter('body_class','my_class_names')`.

You can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/wordpress-hooks.php#L98) of using a filter.

Answer (score 4):

you can add extra classes directly into the function, as arguments;
for permanently, use:

```
body_class('two-sidebars')
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class